# Conversation list repeats the name of the same multiple times

Tags: php, yii2

here is my code from message the controller. In the message center I have left column which displays the list of conversations. The problem is, if a user receives multiple messages from the same sender, then in the conversation list there will be the the same sender's name multiple times (please see the picture below), which I want to have the same sender's name in the conversation list only once.

```
    // get recent messages to show in left column
    $recent = Message::find()
            ->with('sentFrom')
            ->where(['sent_to' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
            ->andfilterWhere([
                'or', 
                ['like', 'subject', $search_subject],
                ['like', 'sent_from', $search_sender],
                ])
            ->orderBy('created_at DESC')
            ->limit(Yii::$app->params['message_chat']['recent_limit'])
            ->all();
```

Comment: I don't know yii, but in general, the solution would be to you to keep track of the sender of the last message (both in and out). If they are the same, you avoid printing the sender of the message name/avatar.

Comment: In continuation to Jauch's comment, consider adding your view's file code - I believe you have a loop that prints all the messages in the chain.

Comment: Lauch thank you for your comment, I appreciate it. Could you please explain it little be more, or add the codes of your idea. Thank you

Comment: Ofir Baruch, thank you for your comment. I have edited my question and added the message view file code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last message from some sender's name try to use [groupBy](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement in your [yii2 query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#$groupBy-detail)

```
$recent = Message::find()
            ->with('sentFrom')
            ->where(['sent_to' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
            ->andfilterWhere([
                'or', 
                ['like', 'subject', $search_subject],
                ['like', 'sent_from', $search_sender],
                ])
            ->orderBy('created_at DESC')
            ->grouoBy([tablne_name.primaryKey])    
            ->limit(Yii::$app->params['message_chat']['recent_limit'])
            ->all();
```

Where:

```
table_name - the mane of table used in sentFrom relation
primaryKey - the primary key of table_name or something other 
             unique, in your case it's maybe something like sender id
```

This query will return you all message with unique primaryKey value.

Comment: b.tokman, thank you for your answer. I appreciate it.  I have added to my question the list of message columns from the database. As you may see "sent_from" is index and "id" is primary. How do you think should I drop the primary key from id and give it to "sent_from"?

Comment: No, in an ideal - sent_from must be the foreign key to user's table. But you can let it be as it is. I think in this case it doesn't matter